# Javascript, loops infinitely and freezes

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, physics, collision

So I'm making a simple physics simulation using HTML5 canvas and javascript. I'm trying to make some realistic collisions, but whenever a collision occurs the code begins to loop infinitely and freezes the page.

I am using Google Chrome 24.0.1312.32 beta-m

When looking at the javascript console the line "console.log("I am colliding with something")" goes crazy and is printed thousands of times per second and completely breaks the page.

I'm not really sure why its' happening and I have no idea what to do. Any help and/or input would really be appreciated.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    if (collide(i)) {
        console.log("I am colliding with something");
        if (typeof getCollideIndx === 'undefined') {
            console.log("collide index is not undefined");
            if (!getCollideIndx(i)) {
                console.log("Made it past null check");
                //...update object based on collision
```

the collide() function is:

```
function collide(b) {
for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    //Distance between each object
    var distance = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((balls[b].x - balls[i].x), 2) + Math.pow(balls[b].y - balls[i].y, 2)));
    if (distance < 32) {
        //must be less than 2*radius -- all radii are the same

        //makes it so that it doesn't return true when checking its own index
        if (!(balls[b].mass == balls[i].mass)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see any infinite loops in there, what is calling your first block of code? If you print something above the first `for` loop does it also get printed a ton?

Comment: Is this within some kind of run loop? Im guessing your loop is running for example at 30 fps possibly more.  If so then you will be calling this code 30 times a second?

Comment: It's within the games' looping function It's called every 30 milliseconds. Whenever I run it though, it gets printed 15,000+ times per second and the page freezes. Here's a link to the page : univeloper.freeiz.com/simulation.html

Comment: Why test `getCollideIndex` for `undefined` and when it IS `undefined`, you then execute `getCollideIndx(i)`?  That is backwards.  I think you meant for it to be `if (typeof getCollideIndx !== 'undefined')`

Comment: It got rid of the freezing, but now I'm running into an uncaught TypeError later in the code. it solved that problem though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see an infinite loop in your code , my best guess would be this statement

```
 if (typeof getCollideIndx === 'undefined')
```

fails every time and whatever function the below code is in is called continuously

```
for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    if (collide(i)) {
        console.log("I am colliding with something");
        if (typeof getCollideIndx === 'undefined') {
            console.log("collide index is not undefined");
            if (!getCollideIndx(i)) {
                console.log("Made it past null check");
                //...update object based on collision
```

also in this , I do not see the point of the for loop as the control always goes back to the calling function (in the collide() function)

Comment: I took that out and it stopped freezing the script, but then I get an uncaught TypeError..I'll see what I can do from there

Answer (score 0):

Well, being trapped in that for loop implies that the index variable `i` is getting set incorrectly somewhere. Without being able to see the entirety of the code I cannot say for sure, but the loop `for(i=0; i<3; i++){...` will be assigning `i` to the `window` object because you have not explicitly scoped it (i.e. `for(var i...`).

See for example [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ssjcb/) where the first function will only run once rather than three times because the same variable `i` is affected in the second function.

Obviously running once != infinite loop, but if the `collide` function does something to `i` (or maybe breaks after it finds a collision?) then the value of `i` will be reset to 0 at the beginning of its for loop each time it's called.

So yeah without some more code I can't say for sure; but my advice in this case is: always use `var` in for loops or weird things can happen!